# Element is outside container

Tags: css

Why is the element outside it's container? At the bottom the yellow element is out of view by about .5px and the container with orange border is too. The scrollbar is overlapping the container too. I thought border-box was meant to make sure inner elements don't go out of the containing element.

```
.inner-element {
    height: 3000px;
    width: 20px;
    background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    border: solid 2px black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Container element

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[image]

The left sidebar on this Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/2-column-scroll-v2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-view%2Fmy-view.component.css

Comment: if you would also provide the html bits this would help reproducing your case

Comment: I guess you have a div inside a div? `<div class="container"><div class="inner-element">&nbsp;</div></div>
`

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` includes padding & border in the calculation of the dimensions of your element. Ex: width 100% and padding 20px the box is still 100% wide.

Answer (score 0):

I have turned your code into a snippet. And the `inner-element` stays within the `container` as expected. I have added the `lightblue` background to the `container` to see it better. So the problem you have is not related to the code you have provided.

```css
.inner-element {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 20px;
  background: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  border: solid 2px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-element">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I put it on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/2-column-scroll-v2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-view%2Fmy-view.component.css